# Capture "Add to cart" click event for all themes in Shopify

Tags: events, shopify, addition, cart

I am trying capture click event of "**Add to cart**" button in Shopify, irrespective of the themes. I am creating an app which, more than one shop owner can use, but everyone using different themes due to which I am not able to capture the click event of the **Add to cart** button.

Comment: You need to develop a logic that matches the maximum number of stores based on the input type, CSS classes, or ids. and make sure it covers most of them and also create a backend settings area where you allow users to add CSS or ID of a button If the automatic mode is not working.

Comment: You simply provide the installation service and configure these things manually.